# How does the cache/expiration heuristic work on a client (Browser, native Mobile or Desktop App)?

Tags: http, caching, server, httpclient, browser-cache

Reading the MDN documentation, the HTTP Definitive Guide Book, and many google searches, if the response does not contain a `Cache-Control: max-age` header or an `Expires` header, the cache can compute a maximum age heuristic via the `Last-Modified` header sent by the server itself.

1. What does the MDN documentation mean when it says "...responses will get stored and reused if certain conditions are met..."? What are those conditions? I know that the client must at least carry out the following formula: `(currentdate - lastModified) * 0.10`. This behavior is done automatically in a browser, storing the response in cache. Is this the only condition?
2. What happens if the server doesn't send the `Last-Modified` header? I managed to find that the browser (chorme) still caches the response, but for how long does the browser cache it?
3. Does the same behavior of a heuristic cache occur in a native Mobile or Desktop App? for example, when using Dart, Java, Kotlin, Rust, Go, etc., when making http client requests with these languages (A browser does it automatically, but in some languages, Does it have to be done programmatically manually?).
4. A more general question, native Mobile and Desktop Apps or using some language as http client, do they automatically perform the http header standards, such as `Cache-Control`, `Transfer-Enncoding`, etc., etc.? Should I do it programmatically manually? Or does it depend on the http language or library being used?

I hope you can help me.